# Manipulação de String em VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Olá, no código que estou desenvolvendo preciso pegar o nome de um arquivo. Usei um OpenFileDialog para que o usuário selecione um arquivo e, após selecionar, o sistema retorna o diretório deste arquivo dentro de uma string. Exemplo: "C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Imagem.png".

Mas eu preciso copiar este arquivo para a pasta do projeto (Application.StartupPath) porém, para isso, eu preciso pegar o nome deste arquivo a partir da barra ("\Imagem.png"), mas não sei como fazê-lo... Tentei de diversas maneiras e não consegui.

Abaixo segue o Código do OpenFileDialog (este funciona):

```
Private Sub btnProcurar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcurar.Click
    Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog()
    OFD.Filter = "Imagens (*.PNG; *.JPG)|*.PNG;*.JPG|" & "All files (*.*)|*.*"
    OFD.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
    OFD.FilterIndex = 1
    OFD.Multiselect = False
    OFD.Title = "Selecionar Comprovante de Depósito"
    If (OFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        NomeArquivo = OFD.FileName
        txtCaminhoComprovante.Text = NomeArquivo
    End If
End Sub
```

Abaixo segue o código que eu citei acima (o que eu não consigo fazer):

```
Private Sub btnConfirmar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfirmar.Click
    If txtValor.TextLength < 4 Then
        MessageBox.Show("O valor informado no campo deve ter no mínimo quatro caracteres! Exemplo: 0.00", "FinanSys - Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        If txtCaminhoComprovante.TextLength < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Você deve selecionar um comprovante do depósito informado!", "FinanSys - Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            If File.Exists(NomeArquivo) Then
                Dim StringReversa As String = StrReverse(NomeArquivo)
                Dim Barra As String = Asc(92)
                Dim CaracterObtido As String = ""
                For i As Integer = 0 To StringReversa.Length - 1
                    If String.Compare(CaracterObtido = StringReversa.Substring(i, 1), Barra) Then
                        CaracterObtido = StringReversa.Substring(i, 1)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                //FileCopy(NomeArquivo, Application.StartupPath)
                MsgBox(CaracterObtido)
            Else
                        MessageBox.Show("O comprovante selecionado não existe!", "FinanSys - Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Resumindo, o que eu preciso é tirar o nome do arquivo "\Imagem.png" da string "C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Imagem.png"

Answer (score 1):

Utilize:

```
Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullpath)
```

O método `System.IO.Path.GetFileName` retorna o nome do arquivo de uma string contendo um diretório completo, que é exatamente o que você quer.
Exemplo:

```
Dim diretorioExemplo As String = "C:\PastaExemplo\ArquivoExemplo.exe"
Dim arquivoExemplo As String = "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(diretorioExemplo)
''arquivoExemplo vai retornar "\ArquivoExemplo.exe"
```

Se quiser mais exemplos, olhe [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você possa utilizar o `.Split()` para fazer isso, veja como ficaria:

```
Dim nomeArquivoArray() As String = NomeArquivo.Split("\")
nomeArquivo = nomeArquivoArray(nomeArquivoArray.Count - 1)
```

Veja funcionando no [rextester](http://rextester.com/UJRCW89305).